# Android Sequence (Skipping method)

Tags: android

i have some problem understanding whats wrong with android code about calling function

as show below, I have 2 private void

```java
cekSaved(place.getName());
addUserInfo(place.getName(),"");
```

i expect the android run ceksaved method first then addUserInfo but android running adduser first then run ceksaved function

i need help understanding this

code is :

```java
private void cekSaved(String param1){
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        DocumentReference newUserInfo = db.collection("trip").document();
        String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        db.collection("trip")
                .whereEqualTo("user_id", userID )
                .whereEqualTo("city", param1)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                status = "ada";
                                Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: "+status);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void addUserInfo(String city, String tittle){



        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        DocumentReference newUserInfo = db.collection("trip").document();
        place_id = newUserInfo.getId();
        Log.i(TAG, "addUserInfo: "+status);
        if(!status.equals("ada")) {
            String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            userTrip usertrip = new userTrip();
            usertrip.setCity(city);
            usertrip.setTittle("My Trip To " + city);
            usertrip.setTrip_id(newUserInfo.getId());
            usertrip.setUser_id(userID);
            Log.i(TAG, "addUserInfo: trip baru telah di buat");


            newUserInfo.set(usertrip).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        ToastMessage("OK");
                    } else {
                        ToastMessage("fail to register");
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{ToastMessage("sudah ada");}

    }
```

Comment: can you show that code please?

Comment: sorry i just added, i have that function called when i clicked a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting values from Firebase, it's an async call, so you don't really know which one will be completed first. You can see that either calls have an onCompleteListener, if you want to run **addUserInfo** after **cekSaved** you have to call addUserInfo inside onCompleteListener of cekSaved method.

Comment: omg... i just know this.. that thing you just say works... thx... i learn thing....so i must do that everytime there in oncomplete listener ?

Comment: Yeah pretty much this @WilliamAi, onCompleteListener will be trigerred whenever a call to firebase completed, so you might want do this if you need to respect the order of your calls! Happy code bro :)